# Cuttoff the Calendar in the Inline VF page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, inline-visualforce, calendar, style

I have used the `<apex:inputField` in VF page add as the inline page in the Account page layout. I am wondering the calendar cutoff like below image. Is there any solution?

[image]

Looking forward your help SFDC stuffs.

**Code Snippet:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" Sliderbar="false" showHeader="false">
<html>
<head>
<apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputLabel>  Birth Date </B></apex:outputLabel>
  <apex:inputField id="bd" value="{!Account.birthdaydate__c}"/>  
</apex:outputPanel>
</head>
<apex:form >
</Page>
```

Answer (score -1):

The VF page will be injected as an iframe inside the account detail page and when you click the date link, the calender element is displayed fully but it cannot pop out of the iframe boundry and that is the reason it appears as cut. You will need to increase the height of the inject VF page or make the scroll available (settings on the page layout) to see the full view of the calendar.

Comment: Could you please suggest the alternative solution? I mage include 10 date fields. So, If i supposed to increase, it will not give the good professional look.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this out

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="false">
<head>
    <apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputLabel>  Birth Date </apex:outputLabel>
      <apex:form>
          <apex:inputField id="bd" value="{!Account.SLAExpirationDate__c}"/>  
      </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</head>
</apex:page>
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: How does this address the problem of the popup being cutoff by the iframe?

Comment: This is nothing resolved.